# How to count SKScenes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can one set up a counter that counts transitions between scenes? I want to show an ad every third game over. When player fails game is transitioned from PlayScene to GameOverScene. And at start of GameOverScene I want to present an Interstitial ad. I have no troubles with ads themselves, just with counting scenes.

That's what I'm currently trying:
In PlayScene:

```
var adcounter = 0

func gameOver() {
adcounter++
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(adcounter, forKey: "overAd")
```

In GameOverScene's didMoveToView:

```
var counterAd : Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("overAd")
    println("ad status \(counterAd)")
```

It always prints 1

**Transitions:**
PlayScene:
When objects are hitting each other –

```
func gameOver() {
    println("TOTAL GAMEOVER")
    adcounter++
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "overScore")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(adcounter, forKey: "overAd")
    var scene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
    var transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.5)
    let skView = self.view as SKView!
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
}
```

GameOverScene: When hit "retry" –

```
func reset() {
    var scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
    var transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.5)
    let skView = self.view as SKView!
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
    }
```

Comment: Uhh, might be a long-shot but maybe use a counter...

Comment: but it always shows 1 if put it in gameOver function. My question is about where to put counter where it will not reset itself when scenes are changed, not about what to use.

Comment: You can use NSUserDefault or singleton or userData of SKScene.

Comment: Where you put the counter / how you construct the logic is pretty much dependent on how you've structured your code. @WangYudong suggest a singleton. This is most often not the right answer, but in games it is not uncommon to have a singleton GameState-object... Another solution would be to have your main viewController handle all scene-changes, then this can keep track of the numbers. There are _loads_ of way to do this, but without knowledge about your project it is hard to suggest anything to specific.

Comment: I'm not familiar with singleton. My game is pretty simple, it has 3 scenes: menu with buttons, play scene and scene for game over. I'm moving between them just by setting `skView.presentScene(PlayScene, transition: transition)`. I thought there is some relatively easy way to store and retrieve a counter. I'm familiar with NSUserDefaults but don't understand how to use them that way

Comment: @TimurTim Just treat NSUserDefaults as a global variable for your counter. Initialize it first time the play scene starts, and increase it when the game over scene starts or before transitioning to the game over scene.

Comment: @WangYudong can you show me an example of such code? I've updated my question to show what am I currently trying to implement and it's not working

Comment: I want to make sure did you transition to your game over more than once, i.e. how many times has `gameOver` been invoked?

Comment: You should increment `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("overAd")` instead of `adcounter` because it will be reset to 0.

Comment: @WangYudong What do you mean? It's like a loop, when player loose, I make a transition to GameOverScene. There is a button "retry" that transition player back to PlayScene, and so on. I'll update my code now with transitions

Comment: How can I do that? I can't ++ them, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one more step and you will get what you want.

Firstly, initialize `overAd` object in `viewDidLoad` of **GameViewController**:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "overAd")
```

Modify your `gameOver` method in **PlayScene** like this:

```
func gameOver() {
    var adcounter = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("overAd")
    adcounter++
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(adcounter, forKey: "overAd")
}
```

Then after you transition to **GameOverScene** and get what saved in object for key `overAd`, you will find it now increments until you reset it.

Comment: I did it but still have 0 every time. Maybe I misunderstood you. I added that code but should I add or delete anything from GameOverScene?

Comment: Oops, that was my fault, sorry! Thank you very much, it works!!